# css technique to apply to a character within a matching tag

Tags: html, css

Given I have the following tag:

```
<label>Hello world *</label>
```

Is there a way to apply a css to the "*" in all label tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order you want to add anything after your label-element you could also use the following pseudo-element:

```
label:after {
   content: "*";
}
```

Comment: A nice way to do this is by adding a class of 'mandatory' (or similar), to your label, so you get: `label.mandatory:after {content:"*";}` You can also set the styles for the generated content, like: `label.mandatory:after {content:"*"; color: red;}`

Comment: This was exactly what I was after! I actually had the embedded spans inside the label tag but this was growing to be too messy and unmanageable. Hence the question for a css solution!

Answer (score 2):

To style the `*`, you must wrap it in something:

```
<label>Hello world <span>*</span></label>
```

The CSS is simple:

```
label span {
    color: red
}
```

If you don't need to support older versions of IE, then go with @Dude's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in a span with a class, yes just the *.

Answer (score -1):

Since you can't style plain text, the common technique is just to put what you want in a span and give the span a name/id/class.

You can also do this inline with:

```
<label>Hello world <span style="position:absolute;font-family:blah">*</span></label>
```

Comment: Every time you use inline styles, a fairy dies.